# Display current timezone like this +03:00 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

```
$timezone = Carbon::now()->format('e'); // Asia/Riyadh
```

Instead of **Asia/Riyadh** I would like **+03:00** to be printed.

Comment: `now()->format('c')` ?

Comment: It returns 2021-03-24T08:27:33+03:00

Comment: `now()->format('r')` this ?

Comment: It returns Wed, 24 Mar 2021 08:29:06 +0300

Comment: you want only time or what

Comment: I only want +03:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timezone = Carbon::now()->format('P');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```php
$timezone = now()->format('P')
```

ref links

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters):

```
echo Carbon::now()->tz->toOffsetName(); // +03:00
```

[Or using CarbonTimeZone](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-timezone):

```
$tz = new CarbonTimeZone('Asia/Riyadh');
echo $tz->toOffsetName(); // +03:00
```

If you're working with an existing Carbon object:

```
echo $tz->toOffsetName($date); // +03:00
```